# Why does files persist on mount points even after switching usb drives?

Tags: linux, mount

I am using a Raspberry PI as MiniDLNA server and a usb drive to store content instead of storing it locally on sd card. 
So I added the usb drive in fstab to get it automatically mount on startup and made a symlink to the same in the home directory.
Symlink
So, my old usb drive was very slow, so I removed the old one and swapped it with a relatively new formatted drive and to my surprise, all files that were present in the old drive were still visible on the new drive.

`usb1 -> /mnt/usb1`

Both drives uses FAT32 as file system and have 8GB of space, mounted at the same mount point `/mnt/usb1` and originally available at `/dev/sda1`

How is that even possible if I swapped the old drive with another formatted and empty drive ?

Comment: Do the files go away if you umount the drive?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes

Comment: Then the files aren't on the drive.

Comment: Hmm, strange. It means they are on the sd card. 
But shouldn't it work. I am mounting the usb drive under a mount point and soft linking it to a the mount point.
Dmesg doesn't show any error about the usb drive not getting mounted.